# Set extension type for open and save dialogs

Tags: python, wxpython

I want the open dialog to filter files by `*.spectrum` or not filter it (`*.* all files`).

I also want the save dialog to suggest a `.spectrum` extension when saving. The common, `new file.ext` where the `new file` is highlighted for us to overwrite.

---

I have set the `wildcard = "*.spectrum"` for both options, but please give me a more complete solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a couple articles on this subject:

- wxPython: [Showing 2 Filetypes in wx.FileDialog](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/02/10/wxpython-showing-2-filetypes-in-wx-filedialog/)
- The [Dialogs of wxPython](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/26/the-dialogs-of-wxpython-part-1-of-2/)

Basically what you want for the open and save dialogs is something like this:

```
wildcard = "Python source (*.spectrum)|*.spectrum|" \
           "All files (*.*)|*.*"
```

Then in the code, you'd do something like this:

```
def onOpenFile(self, event):
    """
    Create and show the Open FileDialog
    """
    dlg = wx.FileDialog(
        self, message="Choose a file",
        defaultDir=self.currentDirectory, 
        defaultFile="",
        wildcard=wildcard,
        style=wx.OPEN | wx.MULTIPLE | wx.CHANGE_DIR
        )
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        paths = dlg.GetPaths()
        print "You chose the following file(s):"
        for path in paths:
            print path
    dlg.Destroy()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def onSaveFile(self, event):
    """
    Create and show the Save FileDialog
    """
    dlg = wx.FileDialog(
        self, message="Save file as ...", 
        defaultDir=self.currentDirectory, 
        defaultFile="", wildcard=wildcard, style=wx.SAVE
        )
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        path = dlg.GetPath()
        print "You chose the following filename: %s" % path
    dlg.Destroy()
```

Note: Code taken directly from my blog and only modified slightly.

Comment: ... and setting `defaultFile="something.spectrum"` suggests a `.spectrum` extension. Thanks.